# ActiveX Control Dispose(true) is not called

Tags: c#, .net, activex

My C# ActiveX Control is hostet in IE 8. I want to execute code when the control is unloaded.

I tried the following:

```
...
public class ActiveXControl : Control 
{
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing) 
    {
        if (disposing) 
        {
            // Cleanup
        }
    }
}
...
```

But disposing is allways false (Called from finalizer). As I need to access managed objects I cannot use that one.

How can I get the cleanup code to be called when the Browser "unloads" the control?

I found the IOleObject::Close method, which is implemented by the Control class but AFAIK ther's no way of overriding its behavior.

Comment: Generally speaking, it's not a good idea to write IE browser extensions (BHOs, Toolbars, or ActiveX controls) in .NET.

Comment: @Eric: It's only used in a well known environment. In my special case I can't think of any diasdvantages. Maybe there's an article about it?

Comment: I have found that the VisibleChanged event fires when you navigate away from the page.
Have you found any other solutions yet?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't done this, but as a suggestion to try: It might be possible to write a bit of javascript embedded in the html of on the web page that will call a method on your activeX control when the page is navigated away from. You could call your cleanup code from this method.

Comment: This sure would work. But I'd prefer a non javascript solution.

Answer (score 1):

You could override OnHandleDestroyed(), called when IE destroys the control window.

Comment: Tried it, but it's never called.